# Chain complex from a degree-2 nilpotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a (not necessarily commutative) associative algebra over a ring $R$, and let $f:R\to Z(A)$ be the corresponding ring homomorphism where $Z(A)$ is the center of $A$. Denote the ring multiplication in $A$ by $x_1\cdot x_2$ for $x_1,x_2\in A$. Then, the scalar $R$-multiplication is given by $(r,x)\mapsto f(r)\cdot x$ for $r\in R$ and $x\in A$.

Suppose there is a degree-2 nilpotent element $n\in A$; namely, $n\cdot n=0$. Define a map $d:A\to A$ by sending $x$ to $d(x)=n\cdot x$. Then, $d(d(x))=n\cdot (n\cdot x)=(n\cdot n)\cdot x=0$; namely $d\circ d=0$.
Note that $A$ is an $R$-module, and $d$ is also an $R$-module homomorphism since $f(r)$ lies in the center of $A$ and $d(f(r)\cdot x)=n\cdot f(r)\cdot x=f(r)\cdot n\cdot x=f(r)\cdot d(x)$.

Therefore, we can naively view $(A,d)$ as a chain complex of $R$-modules, and then we have a homology group $H(A,d)$. One example in my mind is the matrix algebra $A=M_2(R)$ of of all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $R$. Then, there is an obvious degree-2 nilpotent element $n$. Can we compute $H(A,d)$ then?

In general, is this construction applicable in algebraic topology or related fields? It looks like a natural construction and should be documented in some references.

Comment: For your example, taking $n=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$ you can compute $\ker(d)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b\in R\right\}=nA,$ so $H(A,d) = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the algebra $B=k[n]/(n^2)$ and any $B$-module $M$, you have a map $n: M \to M$, so you can define $H(M,n)$ as $\ker n/ \text{im}\, n$. At least in the finitely generated case, I think in general, $H(M,n)=0$ if and only if $M$ is free over $B$.

So in the case you're asking about, given any $A$-module $M$, you can view it as a $B$-module by restriction, and the $n$-homology measures whether $M$ is free over $k[n]/(n^2)$. In particular, your $H(A,d)$ will be zero if and only if $A$ is free when restricted to this subalgebra.

This has been used in homotopy theory to study modules over the Steenrod algebra, whether they're free and other homological properties. See papers of [Adams-Margolis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82368584.pdf), [Anderson-Davis](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02566125), [Miller-Wilkerson](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404981901043), and others. The third of these in fact uses a generalization: if $n^m=0$, then you can define a sort of homology as $\ker n / \text{im}\, (n^m-1)$, and it measures freeness in the same way. (See [Mayer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968874) for maybe the first paper on this.)